# Replace "?" in a squence of numbers

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence

Replace the "?" in the following sequence:$ $
2 7 10 13 14 22 26 27 28 31 49 53 54 57 78 79 **?** 90 101 106 109 110 111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is:

> 81a
>
>  The numbers in the sequence are the op. numbers belonging to sonata 1 to 32 from Beethoven. The missing one is sonata 26.